# Ubuntu 11.04 randomly logs out in middle of use

Tags: 11.04, logout

I can see there is a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35298/ubuntu-11-04-randomly-logs-out) already.Since my problem is not quite the same but quite similar as far as I understand, I am asking it too.

Basically in the middle of my usage i.e. browsing net or running a random application. Ubuntu sends me to the login window and I have to re-login. I do not know if GDM restarts or something else. This is a problem that I face even in the stable release of Ubuntu.

Is there a bug I do not know about?? How can I debug this ?

Here is my `~/.xsession_errors` file output.

```
/etc/gdm/Xsession: Beginning session setup...
Setting IM through im-switch for locale=en_US.
Start IM through /etc/X11/xinit/xinput.d/all_ALL linked to /etc/X11/xinit/xinput.d/default.
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/tmp/keyring-CN4XlZ
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/keyring-CN4XlZ/ssh
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/tmp/keyring-CN4XlZ
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/keyring-CN4XlZ/ssh
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/tmp/keyring-CN4XlZ
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/keyring-CN4XlZ/ssh
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Initializing bailer options...done
Initializing detection options...done
Initializing composite options...done
Initializing opengl options...done
Initializing decor options...done
Initializing vpswitch options...done
Initializing move options...done
Initializing imgsvg options...done
Initializing expo options...done
Initializing mousepoll options...done
Initializing workarounds options...done
Initializing resize options...done
Initializing gnomecompat options...done
Initializing ezoom options...done
Initializing staticswitcher options...done
Initializing obs options...done
Initializing snap options...done
Initializing scale options...done
Initializing wall options...done
Initializing imgjpeg options...done
Initializing grid options...done
Starting Dropbox...** Message: /home/sagar/.config/desktopnova/pidlock already exists, but process with PID 1911 is not DesktopNova. Daemon will continue starting.
Initializing place options...done
Initializing commands options...done
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/home/sagar/.compiz/session/10d8191ee2e3827d13130355181434233600000157530036"
Initializing session options...done

** (process:15832): WARNING **: recent-manager-provider.vala:125: Desktop file for audacious2 was not found
(synapse:15840): GtkHotkey-DEBUG: Listener Type: GtkHotkeyX11Listener
** (nm-applet:15829): DEBUG: old state indicates that this was not a disconnect 0
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 0.6.7
Initializing nautilus-gdu extension
Done!
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: Unity accessibility initialization
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: Shows on edge: 1

Screen geometry changed:
  Monitor 0(primary)
   0x0x1366x768

unity-panel-service: no process found
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: PanelController:: Added Panel for Monitor 0
Initializing unityshell options...done
Initializing unitymtgrabhandles options...done
Starting unity-window-decorator
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: PlaceEntry: Applications
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: PlaceEntry: Commands
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: PlaceEntry: Files & Folders
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: /com/canonical/unity/applicationsplace
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: /com/canonical/unity/filesplace
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: Setting to primary screen rect: x=0 y=0 w=1366 h=768
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: Acquired the name com.canonical.Unity.Launcher on the session bus

** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: TrayChild Rejected: dropbox-client-15846 dropbox Dropbox
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: TrayChild Rejected: synapse synapse Synapse
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: TrayChild Rejected: nm-applet nm-applet Nm-applet
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: TrayChild Accepted: gnote gnote Gnote
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: TrayChild Rejected: gst-keyboard-xkb gnome-settings-daemon Gnome-settings-daemon

(gnote:15839): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_window_thaw_toplevel_updates_libgtk_only: assertion `private->update_and_descendants_freeze_count > 0' failed
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: TrayChild Rejected: battery-indicator battery-status Battery-status
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: IndicatorAdded: libapplication.so
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: IndicatorAdded: libsoundmenu.so
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: IndicatorAdded: libmessaging.so
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: IndicatorAdded: libdatetime.so
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: IndicatorAdded: libsession.so
Setting Update "run_key"
Setting Update "run_command_terminal_key"
Setting Update "initiate_output_edge"
Setting Update "launcher_hide_mode"
Setting Update "panel_opacity"
Setting Update "icon_size"

** (gnome-screensaver:16128): WARNING **: screensaver already running in this session

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: instance of invalid non-instantiatable type `(null)'

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_handler_disconnect: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
** (process:15832): DEBUG: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:174: Inserting 1 events

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_handler_disconnect: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_handler_disconnect: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: MaximizeIfBigEnough: window mapped and already maximized, just undecorate
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: MaximizeIfBigEnough: Guake.py window size doesn't fit

** (<unknown>:15822): WARNING **: Unable to fetch children: Method "Children" with signature "" on interface "org.ayatana.bamf.view" doesn't exist



(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: instance of invalid non-instantiatable type `(null)'

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_handler_disconnect: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_handler_disconnect: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_handler_disconnect: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
** (process:15832): DEBUG: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:174: Inserting 1 events
loaded md5.js

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_handler_disconnect: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_handler_disconnect: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: MaximizeIfBigEnough: window mapped and already maximized, just undecorate

(firefox-bin:18524): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: dbusmenu_menuitem_property_set_shortcut: assertion `gtk_accelerator_valid(key, modifier)' failed
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: MaximizeIfBigEnough: Guake.py window size doesn't fit

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: instance of invalid non-instantiatable type `(null)'

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_handler_disconnect: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_handler_disconnect: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_handler_disconnect: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: MaximizeIfBigEnough: Guake.py window size doesn't fit
** (process:15832): DEBUG: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:174: Inserting 1 events
15846 ?        00:00:01 dropbox
22490 ?        00:00:00 unity-dropbox-s
/usr/bin/unity-dropbox-share: line 28: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script
Error setting attribute: Error setting file metadata: No such file or directory
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: Connected to proxy

(<unknown>:15822): dee-WARNING **: Transaction from com.canonical.Unity.FilesPlace.SectionsModel is in the past. Ignoring transaction.

(<unknown>:15822): dee-WARNING **: Transaction from com.canonical.Unity.FilesPlace.GroupsModel is in the past. Ignoring transaction.

(<unknown>:15822): dee-WARNING **: Transaction from com.canonical.Unity.FilesPlace.GlobalGroupsModel is in the past. Ignoring transaction.
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: Connected to proxy
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: Connected to proxy

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_bus_own_name: assertion `g_dbus_is_name (name) && !g_dbus_is_unique_name (name)' failed

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_bus_watch_name: assertion `g_dbus_is_name (name)' failed

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_bus_own_name: assertion `g_dbus_is_name (name) && !g_dbus_is_unique_name (name)' failed

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_bus_watch_name: assertion `g_dbus_is_name (name)' failed

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_connection_register_object: assertion `object_path != NULL && g_variant_is_object_path (object_path)' failed

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_connection_register_object: assertion `object_path != NULL && g_variant_is_object_path (object_path)' failed

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_handler_disconnect: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(<unknown>:15822): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_handler_disconnect: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: MaximizeIfBigEnough: Nautilus window size doesn't fit

** (nautilus:15824): WARNING **: Invalid borders specified for theme pixmap:
        /home/sagar/.themes/nautilus/null.png,
borders don't fit within the image

** (nautilus:15824): WARNING **: invalid source position for bilinear gradient

** (nautilus:15824): WARNING **: invalid source position for vertical gradient

** (nautilus:15824): WARNING **: invalid source position for horizontal gradient

** (nautilus:15824): WARNING **: Invalid borders specified for theme pixmap:
        /home/sagar/.themes/nautilus/null.png,
borders don't fit within the image

** (nautilus:15824): WARNING **: invalid source position for bilinear gradient

** (nautilus:15824): WARNING **: invalid source position for vertical gradient

** (nautilus:15824): WARNING **: invalid source position for horizontal gradient
** (<unknown>:15822): DEBUG: MaximizeIfBigEnough: Guake.py window size doesn't fit
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.


** (nautilus:15824): WARNING **: invalid source position for bilinear gradient

** (nautilus:15824): WARNING **: invalid source position for vertical gradient

** (nautilus:15824): WARNING **: invalid source position for horizontal gradient

(nautilus:15824): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:15824): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:15824): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:15824): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:15824): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:15824): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:15824): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:15824): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:15824): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:15824): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:15824): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:15824): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:15824): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:15824): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:15824): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:15824): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:15824): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:15824): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:15824): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:15824): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:15824): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:15824): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

(nautilus:15824): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed
```

I recently got an update to gnome-sessions. I hope that solves the problem, however I can only be sure after testing for few days...Will update the situation.

UPDATE: Nope no progress, got the update but the problem persists. But it seems to be a lot less frequent than it used to be. I am following up this question as some people suggested me to re-install but now I face [Unity freezes after compiz configuration change](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40261/unity-freezes-after-compiz-configuration-change)

Comment: I have the same exact problem...I hope someone answers this question...

Comment: You could check the file `.xsession-errors` in your home directory for any suspicious warnings or errors that occured right before you were dropped to gdm.

Comment: This is very annoying....today it logged out like 5 times during the day randomly while I was working...

Comment: The logging out is likely your X server crashing, this should instead be filed as a bug report, [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: so do I type "ubuntu-bug xserver" ?

Comment: Maybe this bug is related to yours: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/760695

Comment: I have had this same problem since upgrading. I hope we get this answered. It only happens when I am on my web browser for some reason.  I don't work on a server.  I just pull the plug on my computer and restart it.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I just installed the final version of Ubuntu 11.04 (I'm running it in an AMD Athlon X2). So this has nothing to do with hardware?

Comment: @Nik `ubuntu-bug xorg` will grab the right information from your system and send it to the bug tracker; "logging out" is usually X crashing and kicking you back to GDM.

Comment: @Jorge..thanks..I shall do it when it logs out again randomly..

Comment: [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) this has been reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/760695) and as such is now closed.

Comment: Same problem here on 11.10 and Lenovo SL400. Anyone has solution for it?

Answer (score 3):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/778490).

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Unity or GNOME? Try the other. If that doesn't work, I would suggest Try Xubuntu (to see if it is GNOME). If all that fails, Backup your home partition or folder, and copy /var/cache/apt to another folder, and re-install. Use the Packages from the cache to re-install your applications.

Comment: I have reinstalled ubuntu 11.04 completely...copied all files back again....going to see if the problem happens again.

Answer (score 1):

That can be video driver crashing. What is your video card? Do you use proprietary driver? If yes, try another version, or try removing it completely. 
Or, unfortunately, it can be many others pieces of hardware. X server is a colossus on clay legs, and most vulnerable to hardware faults. Check you memory (memtest86), HDD (fsck, smart), temperatures (lm-sensors). Try switching off all unnecessary hardware and software. I had seen X server crashes when EiskalDC++ tried to index a 100Gb file, for example. 
Have you read logs, dmesg? Anything suspicious? 
P.S. Turn off compiz. It is on by default in ubuntu.

Comment: I have core processor integrated graphics. Obviously if I am using unity then compiz should be on. shouldn't it ??

Comment: Well compiz should definitely be on if you run unity since unity is essentially a compiz plugin. I have this same problem and have the laptop integrated intel graphics card. I have submitted a bug.

Comment: According to this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24977/24978#24978 if you turn off graphical effects, you'll be using metacity in unity.

Answer (score 1):

Try (in a Terminal, without SUDO):

```
unity --reset
```

and then don't touch CCSM (Compiz Settings) again. I don't know if this really helps in your case but I'm in the same situation and currently testing if the crashes still occur.

Comment: But do you think Unity is causing these crashes??

Comment: Easy way to find out is to use old Gnome for a while, and see what happens.