# Unity freezes after compiz configuration change

Tags: unity, compiz, freeze

Well this is a follow-up question regarding [Ubuntu 11.04 randomly logs out in middle of use](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36399/ubuntu-11-04-randomly-logs-out-in-middle-of-use). After some people suggested I re-install I used the beta1 iso to reinstall and upgraded instantly about 3-4 times(the whole process). But now I am facing a bizarre situation where if I change something than default compiz settings it freezes and I cannot do anything other then drop to tty1 and reboot. The problem will persists on reboot as well every session. I was wondering if it was `unity` or `compiz`. Is the default compiz not to be altered for use with unity. Basically I want to disable

animations
desktop zooms etc and enable some compiz functionality.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

I have had the exact same problem on my system. Unity is really buggy right now and does not work well with  other compiz plugins, especially when you mess around with the settings.

Try enabling plugins that do not conflict with others that unity is using(It gives you a warning when you try to). You could also try disabling the unity plugin, tweaking to your hearts content, then re-enabling unity and resolving all issues that it alerts you to. The latter worked for me to a certain extent.

Unity was still a little too buggy for me to use everyday, I would recommend choosing the 'Ubuntu Classic' Desktop from the login screen and then tweaking compiz to your hearts content. I have everything from 'wobbly windows' to 'desktop cube' working like a charm with unity disabled.