# Natty crashes randomly and jumps to login

Tags: 11.04, ati, intel-graphics, login-screen

Sometimes when I work on Natty 32bit the screen goes black and jumps to the login-screen.
i don't know how to reproduce this bug, but it seems it occurs when starting Applications.

Anyone has a solution to this?
Thanks!

Comment: I asked about this a while ago. http://askubuntu.com/questions/36399/ubuntu-11-04-randomly-logs-out-in-middle-of-use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since installing `xserver-xorg-video-intel` package from the `natty-proposed` repository, i have never again experienced this bug.
Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me as well in 11.04. The reason is that bugs in Unity causes the X server to shut down. Which throws you to the log in screen. Hopefully this will be fixed in future updates to Unity.

Comment: As far as I know, this doesn't happen on PC's with NVidia Graphics cards, but on Computers with Intel cards? Can you agree to that?

Comment: I am on Intel card and I can confirm this.

Comment: I'm using a ATI graphics card and I experience this as well. It's not just Intel cards.

Comment: I have intel + ati graphics, I can confirm this too. Yesterday it crashed 2-3 times.

Comment: I have an Nvidia card. This doesn't happen as often as it seems to happen for you all, but I have had this occur 2-3 times now in the past few weeks.