# I am being logged out when I start chromium browser?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, chromium

When I start chromium browser I get logged out and I get the startup screen. How can I check what causes this? I have tried re-installing chromium but that did not work.

Comment: This: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2043119 got me to this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/144792/how-to-stop-my-12-04-randomly-loging-me-out Might be worth a try :)

Comment: thanks, i have issues with nvidia 310.19 can't remove the kernel module and install the old driver nvidia-173

Comment: resolved by uninstalling the manually installed 310.19 and installing nvidia-current (295.40)

Comment: Could you make that an answer and accept it? That way the system knows it is answered (and does not send it to the top of the list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved by uninstalling the manually installed 310.19 and installing nvidia-current (295.40).