# ubuntu 14.04 logs out every 5 minutes

Tags: 14.04

I have Ubuntu 14.04. Today suddenly it started to log out abruptly every 5 minutes. It was running fine before. but now I cannot even read the error messages.. what should I do..

Edit: I noticed that it happens when i run  applications like firefox or CompizConfig settings manager.

My graphics card driver is Nvidia binary driver- version 331.89 from NVIDIA-331, graphic cards on my system are Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller and Nvidia GEFORCE 750M. Currently I am using intel

Comment: Does it log out completely or just locks the screen? Does the system give an error? If it's not an error and if it just locks the screen, you could check your `Brightness & Lock settings`, found under `System Preferences`.

Comment: It logs out completely. I have to login again.. there is black screen a few seconds with some messages i cannot read because it disappears quickly and then i have to login again

Comment: There is a similar issue discussed in askubuntu: [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/144792/how-to-stop-my-12-04-randomly-loging-me-out).

Comment: Or it could be the graphics card driver. What graphics card does your system have?

Comment: I think this is happening when i try to use firefox, I have been using chrome since this morning and everything was fine, i started firefox and it logged out again. I removed firefox and re installed it and then problem is still there

Comment: My graphics card driver is Nvidia binary driver- version 331.89 from NVIDIA-331

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Seems to me that this is due to a potentially incorrect update from this Monday. Please try to update your `xserver-xorg-video-intel`, a new version has been released now, maybe they realized this issue.

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

I did this, so far so good, I could not yet reproduce the crash.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to ubuntu too, but you should check into the *system config*, then *shine&lock*, inside there should be turn off the screen then choose the time you want.

See if that helps.

Comment: Can you please explain why this would help?