# Can I use metacity's move_to_side keybindings from Unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity, shortcut-keys, metacity

I noticed that gconf-editor has some interesting keybindings for metacity in
/apps/metacity/window_keybindings/:

- move_to_center
- move_to_corner_ne
- move_to_side_e

Can I use these from Unity in 11.04?

I'm already using some others (like toggle_maximized), but I cannot get the move_to ones to work.

I [wrote a script](https://github.com/pydave/daveconfig/blob/master/unix/scripts/aerosnap.sh) for 10.10 to do something similar (I think), but if I can use native functionality, that would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was a bit confused about Unity using compiz vs metacity, but according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24977/why-does-ubuntu-use-two-window-managers-compiz-and-metacity/24978#24978) metacity is only used for no special effects. However, it looks like some settings under metacity are used by compiz. (No point in requiring the user to maintain two sets of settings.)

So since I'm using compiz, I need to install [compizconfig-settings-manager](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

and use that to set the shortcuts in **Window Management > Grid**. Changing the shortcuts there works.